# Why image of local not showing?

Tags: react-native

In react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image
} from 'react-native';

class Myapp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Welcome to React Native~~
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit index.android.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Shake or press menu button for dev menu
        </Text>
        <Image 
          style={styles.picture}
          source={require('./img/flowers.png')} 
        />
        <Text style={styles.end}>
          Why image not showing?
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  end:{
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin:10,
  }
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  picture: {
    width:50,
    height:80,
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Myapp', () => Myapp);
```

When I want to show image in linking(use uri) , The image is showing 
But when I want to show image in local, The image(flowers.png) is not showing ..
I'm sure that flowers.png is in img folder . 
the result of this code is

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2psQO.png)

Why image in local not showing ..?

Comment: What is your project folder structure ? Are you sure the image path is correct?

Comment: Im sure that the image path is correct have i to upload other photo?

Comment: Check your IDE's log or even the Dev server's log for errors. Is the image corrupt?